# can't get jquery toggle here - logic help needed

Tags: jquery

The point is to toggle some fieldsets but, depending on the scenario you may have either one or two fieldsets active. This should work on both cases.

http://jsfiddle.net/4XQ2u/18/

This works only if we have **one** fieldset appearing.

If you duplicate the fieldsets and test it again, you will notice that, if we have **two** fieldsets, the links that trigger should also change, but they don't, making the link text to be absurd.

http://jsfiddle.net/4XQ2u/40/

Am I using the wrong tool for this job, or is it a logic issue on this code ?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? in the second case just change the 1 for 2. It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is listening for someone to click on the button before it does anything. The simplest solution is to add an if statement at the bottom of your code:

```
if($('#localized fieldset').length > 1)
{
  $(".trigger").toggle();
}
```

Comment: At the bottom I believe it will do nothing. I've added on the top. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/4XQ2u/44/